# Find the matrix in canonical base of the following orthogonal transformation. Then, find $f(4,-1,1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations

Find the matrix in canonical base of the following orthogonal transformation $f:\mathbb{R^3}$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R^3}$ a rotation of axis $<(2,-2,-1)>$ and angle $\pi/2$. Then, find $f(4,-1,1)$.

Let's call $H^{\perp}$$=<(2/3,-2/3,-1/3)>$ orthonormal base form with the rotation axis defined.

Then, we need to find the perpendicular plane to $H^{\perp}$, let's call it $H$, that is our rotational plane.

Then I defined the ortonormal base with a ortonormal base of $H^{\perp}$ and $H$:

$B=< H^{\perp}\oplus H> =<(2/3,-2/3,-1/3),(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2),(-\sqrt{2}/6,\sqrt{2}/6,-2\sqrt{2}/3>$

To get the matrix in canonical base I used the change of basis: $|f|_E=C_{BE}|f|_BC_{EB}$ where $C_{BE}$ is our matrix form with the vectors of the base $B$ written in columns and $C_{EB}$ is the inverse of $C_{BE}$, and where $|f|_B$ comes from considering the structure of a rotational matrix with our angle $\pi/2$:

$|f|_B\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Then, I'm having troubles to could find $f(4,-1,1)$, I thought that I could get it by finding the vector $w_1=(4,-1,1)/||(4,-1,1)||$, in coordinates of the base $B$ and then $f(4,-1,1)_B=$$|f|_Bw_1$ Any of my reasoning is incorrect? In the case I'm wrong with something, how can I do it?

Comment: Why are you normalizing $w_1$?

Comment: Maybe I wrongly assumed I should. Isn't necessary?

Comment: That’s the vector you’re rotating, so wouldn’t you want to preserve its length?

Comment: Once you have the rotation matrix, why not simply apply it to the vector to be rotated instead of going through all of the extra (albeit not incorrect) work of converting to another basis? You’ll have to convert back to the standard basis afterwards, anyway.

Comment: I had in mind you cannot apply the matrix of a transformation to a vector which isn't written in coordinates of the input subspace. Is incorrect?

Comment: Calculate $|f|_E(4,-1,1)$, these are the coordinates of $f(4,-1,1)$ in the canonical base. Then transform in back to the basis $B$ with $C_{EB}$ and expand these coordinates in the basis $B$ to find $f(4,-1,1)$.

Comment: Great. What do you mean by "expand these coordinates"?

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ be the matrix whose columns are the vector of your orthonormal base.
The matrix of $f$ respect to the standard basis is $|f|_E=B|f|_BB^{-1}$.
The components of $f(4,-1,1)$ are given by matrix multiplication of $|f|_E$ with the column vector of $(4,-1,1)$.